How to align checkbox text vertically in JavaFX?
We use AtlantaFX. This is the code:
public class NewMain extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(new Dracula().getUserAgentStylesheet());
        var checkBox = new CheckBox("aaaaaaaaa");
        var label = new Label("bbbbbbbbbbbb");
        var toolBar = new ToolBar(checkBox, label);
        toolBar.setMinHeight(40);
        var root = new VBox(toolBar);

        var scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

This is the result:

As you see CheckBox text is not aligned with Label text (CheckBox text is lower). Could anyone say how to fix it using CSS?

Ideally, I think this should be as simple as setting the style -fx-alignment: baseline-left; on the toolbar, but unfortunately that did not work when I tried it.

What happens without setMinHeight()?
